# Where is My Xaml icon?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

i created  Wpf projext but i can see blue icon at my home but at my company undefined icon. Where is blue icon?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try restoring the Visual Studio file associations:

go to Tools > Options > Environment > General - and then click the button at the bottom that says 'Restore File Associations' hit ok and you should be good (maybe after restarting VS)